# How to get the default value for a ValueType Type with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, struct, default, default-constructor

If I have a generic type parameter that is a value type and I want to know if a value is equal to the default I test it like this:

```
static bool IsDefault<T>(T value){
    where T: struct
    return value.Equals(default(T));
}
```

If I don't have a generic type parameter, then it seems like I would have to use reflection.  If the method has to work for all value types, then **Is there a better way to perform this test than what I am doing here? :**

```
static bool IsDefault(object value){
   if(!(value is ValueType)){
      throw new ArgumentException("Precondition failed: Must be a ValueType", "value");
   }
   var @default = Activator.CreateInstance(value.GetType());
   return value.Equals(@default);  
}
```

On a side note, Is there anything I am not considering here with respect to evaluating Nullable structs?

Comment: Looks okay to me.  Good thing that the `value is ValueType` test will also check for `null`.  :)

Comment: Two questions: 1. why not use the generic method? 2. Why not make the parameter to second method a `ValueType` since you're just going to complain anyway?

Comment: Or do `if (!(value is ValueType)) return value == null;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the following extension methods useful and will work for all types:

```
public static object GetDefault(this Type t)
{
    return t.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(t) : null;
}

public static T GetDefault<T>()
{
    var t = typeof(T);
    return (T) GetDefault(t);
}

public static bool IsDefault<T>(T other)
{
    T defaultValue = GetDefault<T>();
    if (other == null) return defaultValue == null;
    return other.Equals(defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't appear to work in a pure reflection scenario where you don't know the type of either, the one coming in is an object. So the `T` in `IsDefault` is just object, and `.Equals` just checks for reference equality. At least in my case boxed `0` was not equal to `Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType)` where `propertyType` is `int`

Comment: I've been trying your solution and I've found even shorter (I believe that it should work all right too): `public static object GetDefault<T>(T obj)
        {
            return default(T);
        }`

Answer (score 8):

Old question but the accepted answer doesn't work for me so I submit this (probably can be made better):

```
public static object GetDefault(this Type type)
{   
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
    {
        var valueProperty = type.GetProperty("Value");
        type = valueProperty.PropertyType;
    }

    return type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null;
}
```

With the following results:

```
typeof(int).GetDefault();       // returns 0
typeof(int?).GetDefault();      // returns 0
typeof(DateTime).GetDefault();  // returns 01/01/0001 00:00:00
typeof(DateTime?).GetDefault(); // returns 01/01/0001 00:00:00
typeof(string).GetDefault();    // returns null
typeof(Exception).GetDefault(); // returns null
```

Comment: FYI, this is **the answer.**

Answer (score 2):

I would require `ValueType` as the parameter to simplify:

```
static bool IsDefault(ValueType value){
   var @default = Activator.CreateInstance(value.GetType());
   return value.Equals(@default);  
}
```

Comment: cdhowie's comment has me rethinking this solution, as it does not handle the potential `NullReferenceException`. Be sure to handle that case or throw an `ArgumentNullException` if the parameter is null.

Answer (score 0):

> On a side note, Is there anything I am not considering here with
>   respect to evaluating Nullable structs?

Yes, you are missing something.  By taking an `object` as the parameter in you are requiring calling code to box `Nullable<T>` types (which converts them to null or to their `T` Value).  So if you pass a nullable, your `is/throw` will throw because `null` will never be a value type.

**Edit:** As @cdhowie said, you'll need to check for null.  This will work for Nullable types as well.

Comment: Another thing to consider with nullable structs is that there's no way to distinguish between e.g. an `int` with value zero and an `int?` with value zero, even though zero is the default value for the first of those types, but is not the default value for the second.